# UNION do not my sql column results for ODBC query

Tags: sql, union

I have a SQL query where I am trying to add the Date to output into the column but it gives me the following error

> the type of the result columns of the queries in UNION do no match. Mismatch with select-item number 3.

Anybody able to shed some light on what might be going wrong with my code as per the two samples below?

This is the code I am trying to update

```
SELECT DIH_DBTNO as Debtor, JT_DES as Description, DIH_DATE as Date,

CASE WHEN JT_TYPE=73 THEN JT_ITMNO
WHEN JT_TYPE=76 THEN 'LABOUR'
ELSE 'WORK SHEET' END as Item,

SUM(JT_AQTYHOURS) AS 'Qty',
SUM(JT_ORDERTOTAL) AS 'Sales',
SUM(JT_ACOST*JT_AQTYHOURS) AS 'Cost'


FROM Debtors_Invoice_Header_File, Job_Master_File, Job_Transaction_File
WHERE JOB_NO = DIH_JOBNO
AND JOB_UNIQUE = JT_LINK
AND JT_INVOICED > 0
AND JT_TYPE <>84
AND DIH_DBTNO like ?
AND DIH_DATE >=?
AND DIH_DATE <=?

GROUP BY DIH_DBTNO, JT_DES, DIH_DATE

UNION ALL

SELECT DIH_DBTNO as Debtor, DIL_ITMNO as Item, DIL_DES as Description, DIH_DATE as Date,
SUM(DIL_QTYDEL) AS 'Qty',
SUM(DIL_ORDERTOTAL) AS 'Sales',
SUM(DIL_COST*DIL_QTYDEL) AS 'Cost'

FROM Debtors_Invoice_Header_File, Debtors_Invoice_Line_File
WHERE DIH_LINK = DIL_DIHLINK
AND DIL_TRANTYPE = 73
AND DIH_DBTNO like ?
AND DIH_DATE >=?
AND DIH_DATE <=?

GROUP BY DIH_DBTNO, DIL_ITMNO, DIL_DES, DIH_DATE
```

The following code does work, but it is not outputting the date into the columns.

```
SELECT DIH_DBTNO as Debtor, JT_DES as Description,

CASE WHEN JT_TYPE=73 THEN JT_ITMNO
WHEN JT_TYPE=76 THEN 'LABOUR'
ELSE 'WORK SHEET' END as Item,

SUM(JT_AQTYHOURS) AS 'Qty',
SUM(JT_ORDERTOTAL) AS 'Sales',
SUM(JT_ACOST*JT_AQTYHOURS) AS 'Cost'


FROM Debtors_Invoice_Header_File, Job_Master_File, Job_Transaction_File
WHERE JOB_NO = DIH_JOBNO
AND JOB_UNIQUE = JT_LINK
AND JT_INVOICED > 0
AND JT_TYPE <>84
AND DIH_DBTNO like ?
AND DIH_DATE >=?
AND DIH_DATE <=?

GROUP BY DIH_DBTNO, JT_DES

UNION ALL

SELECT DIH_DBTNO as Debtor, DIL_ITMNO as Item, DIL_DES as Description,
SUM(DIL_QTYDEL) AS 'Qty',
SUM(DIL_ORDERTOTAL) AS 'Sales',
SUM(DIL_COST*DIL_QTYDEL) AS 'Cost'

FROM Debtors_Invoice_Header_File, Debtors_Invoice_Line_File
WHERE DIH_LINK = DIL_DIHLINK
AND DIL_TRANTYPE = 73
AND DIH_DBTNO like ?
AND DIH_DATE >=?
AND DIH_DATE <=?

GROUP BY DIH_DBTNO, DIL_ITMNO, DIL_DES
```

Any pointers on where I might be going wrong would be appreciated,
Thanks in advance

Comment: It is recommended to use [ANSI Join Syntax](https://www.oratechinfo.co.uk/ansi_joins.html). Are you using Oracle database?

Answer (score 1):

Date is the third column in first part and 4th column in the second part.In union all the sequences of columns and the data type must be same.

Try this and let me know if it works:

```
SELECT DIH_DBTNO as Debtor, JT_DES as Description, DIH_DATE as Date,

    CASE WHEN JT_TYPE=73 THEN JT_ITMNO
    WHEN JT_TYPE=76 THEN 'LABOUR'
    ELSE 'WORK SHEET' END as Item,

    SUM(JT_AQTYHOURS) AS 'Qty',
    SUM(JT_ORDERTOTAL) AS 'Sales',
    SUM(JT_ACOST*JT_AQTYHOURS) AS 'Cost'


    FROM Debtors_Invoice_Header_File, Job_Master_File, Job_Transaction_File
    WHERE JOB_NO = DIH_JOBNO
    AND JOB_UNIQUE = JT_LINK
    AND JT_INVOICED > 0
    AND JT_TYPE <>84
    AND DIH_DBTNO like ?
    AND DIH_DATE >=?
    AND DIH_DATE <=?

    GROUP BY DIH_DBTNO, JT_DES, DIH_DATE

    UNION ALL

    SELECT DIH_DBTNO as Debtor, DIL_DES as Description, DIH_DATE as Date,
     DIL_ITMNO as Item,
    SUM(DIL_QTYDEL) AS 'Qty',
    SUM(DIL_ORDERTOTAL) AS 'Sales',
    SUM(DIL_COST*DIL_QTYDEL) AS 'Cost'

    FROM Debtors_Invoice_Header_File, Debtors_Invoice_Line_File
    WHERE DIH_LINK = DIL_DIHLINK
    AND DIL_TRANTYPE = 73
    AND DIH_DBTNO like ?
    AND DIH_DATE >=?
    AND DIH_DATE <=?

    GROUP BY DIH_DBTNO, DIL_ITMNO, DIL_DES, DIH_DATE
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query.

```
SELECT DIH_DBTNO as Debtor, JT_DES as Description, DIH_DATE as Date,

CASE WHEN JT_TYPE=73 THEN JT_ITMNO
WHEN JT_TYPE=76 THEN 'LABOUR'
ELSE 'WORK SHEET' END as Item,

SUM(JT_AQTYHOURS) AS 'Qty',
SUM(JT_ORDERTOTAL) AS 'Sales',
SUM(JT_ACOST*JT_AQTYHOURS) AS 'Cost'


FROM Debtors_Invoice_Header_File, Job_Master_File, Job_Transaction_File
WHERE JOB_NO = DIH_JOBNO
AND JOB_UNIQUE = JT_LINK
AND JT_INVOICED > 0
AND JT_TYPE <>84
AND DIH_DBTNO like ?
AND DIH_DATE >=?
AND DIH_DATE <=?

GROUP BY DIH_DBTNO, JT_DES, DIH_DATE

UNION ALL

SELECT DIH_DBTNO as Debtor, DIL_DES as Description, DIH_DATE as Date, DIL_ITMNO as Item, 
SUM(DIL_QTYDEL) AS 'Qty',
SUM(DIL_ORDERTOTAL) AS 'Sales',
SUM(DIL_COST*DIL_QTYDEL) AS 'Cost'

FROM Debtors_Invoice_Header_File, Debtors_Invoice_Line_File
WHERE DIH_LINK = DIL_DIHLINK
AND DIL_TRANTYPE = 73
AND DIH_DBTNO like ?
AND DIH_DATE >=?
AND DIH_DATE <=?
GROUP BY DIH_DBTNO, DIL_ITMNO, DIL_DES
```

I just changes the position of `item` column. The base is that in `UNION` or `UNION ALL`, all corresponding column types must be same and exact no. of columns should be present in each `UNION`

So, `Debtor` should be at same column number in both `UNION` is.e, 1. Same for `JT_DES` column 2 and same for `ITEM` column 4. Or you can change the ordering, but it should be same in both UNION.

Hope this would help.